# Why is my choice field still required?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have some field in my Contact entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=6, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"male", "female"})
 */
 protected $gender;
```

And a form for creating contacts:

```
$builder->add('firstName')
                ->add('lastName')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('gender','choice',array(
                        'choices'   => array('male' => 'male', 'female' => 'female'),
                        'required'  => false,
                    ));
```

This should result in a NOT mandatory field AFAIK.
Still the form tells me that I have to select a gender. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make the Assert\Choices annotation compatible with a nullable value :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"male", "female", null})
 */
 protected $gender;
```

Comment: SORRY!, I changed the code to make it more understandable, unfortunately I messed it up and therefore your answer is correct, but addresses another issue. I just edited my question- now it represents my REAL problem.

Comment: Maybe the Assert\Choices annotation is not compatible with a nullable value. Or try this annotation @Assert\Choice(choices = {"male", "female", null})