# Symfony 2 form field radio required=false?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is part of my entity class :

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="student", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $student;
```

This part of my form class :

```
 $builder
    ->add('student', 'choice', ['label'=> false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => (Array)new StudentEnum(),
   ])
        ;
```

Ad this is output :

```
<input id="xxxxx_0" type="radio" value="4" required="required" name="xxxxx[student]">
<label class="required" for="xxxxxV_student_0">Nie</label>
```

...

My problem is that my input tag should not have attribute "required" becouse I have set nullable=true in entity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is `required => false` and `empty_value => false`

```
$builder
        ->add('student', 'choice', [
                'label'=> false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choices' => (Array)new StudentEnum(),
                'required' => false,
                'empty_value' => false
        ]);
```

Comment: this solution is good until Symfony 2.8, then you must use "placeholder" option, since "empty_value" has been deprecated in 2.7 (and removed in 3.0)

Answer (score 4):

As described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#required),

```
required
type: Boolean default: true
```

`required` option default value is set to `true`, so you should then set it to `false`.

```
builder->add('student', 'choice', array(
          'label'=> false,
          'expanded' => true,
          'required' => false,
          //...
   ))
;
```

Also, you can read from documentation that,

> This is superficial and independent from validation. At best, if you let Symfony 
>   guess your field type, then the value of this option will be guessed from your 
>   validation information.

You need then to set a validation rule that take into account the fact that your field should not be required in order to let your form set the right value of required.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604587/symfony2-why-is-my-choice-field-still-required) may probably help.

Comment: I had tried this before and this adding extra radio on top and I don't want that.

Comment: I have set      * @Assert\Choice(choices = {4,3,2,1, null}) but nothing changed.

Comment: OK I have found the solution 
                    'required' => false,
                    'empty_value' => false

Comment: @user2156980 You're welcome. It's good to know that empty_value should also be set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 3.0 `empty_value` is removed and you need to use `placeholder` instead:

```
 $builder
        ->add(
              'student', 
              'choice', 
              [
                'label'=> false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choices' => (Array)new StudentEnum(),
                'required' => false,
                'placeholder' => null
              ]
         );
```